# How can I edit and run Apple Script with an editor other than Script Editor?

Tags: applescript, automator, text-editor, textmate, javascript-automation

I've recently been writing more AppleScript, now that Apple has added Javascript support.

But how can I edit and run Javascript Automation code in an editor other than the built-in Script Editor? My ideal editor would be TextMate, but anything that has good syntax highlighting and automatic indenting would be good enough for me.

Comment: Isn't the code just text which can be edited "anywhere"?

Comment: No, that would be nice. It's a binary file.

Comment: Javascript for Automation is pretty much a mess, but any text editor can be used in conjunction with the `osascript`, `osacompile`, and `osadecompile` shell utilities.

Comment: RE: "now that Apple has added Javascript support." -- That comes across as though **Apple** just introduced it, but  the **JavaScript for Automation** feature was introduced by **Apple** in **Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite**, six and a half years ago!

Comment: @Bill It's only a binary file if you make it one.  You are looking at the compiled result of a script.  I've been creating AppleScript in TextMate for years.

Comment: @MarcWilson @red_menace Can you elaborate on that? What file extension do I use for an uncompiled Apple Script? Can I only run plain text scripts only with `osascript`?

Comment: Use whatever extension you like.  Mine are all .applescript files. If I need to run it outside of FastScripts, I have a makefile that goes along with it that runs osacompile.